# 'Would' in context

Tags: grammar

Would you be so kind to help me out with this sentence?

> It does seem strange that someone **would spend** that much money in a burger shop.

I don't really understand why "would" is used there.
What grammatical topic is that? Does it have anything to do with Conditionals?
I would like to learn more about that phenomenon so a couple of links would be a good idea.

Comment: *You are in the shop. You stare at a very expensive burger, which doesn't appeal to you (too small,  too dry, stuffed with the ingredients you don't like). And you go "It seems strange that someone would spend that much money on that". You look around, no one buys anything.* Here, "would" indicates an imaginary situation.

Comment: The cited example combines elements of ***would** = **hypothetical** [conditional]* and ***would** = [past tense of] **will** with allusions to **willingness*** (...that someone is / should be ***prepared to voluntarily*** do something).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Would*** is used to indicate hypotheticals. It's also used to indicate future-in-past, but that's a separate use. It is often referred to as forming a subjunctive in English, though not all subjunctives require such a modal.

Comment: can I say "It seems strange that someone spends/will spend that much money on this burger" if I know for sure that someone will eventually buy it? :)

Comment: I would say "It seems strange that someone **is going to spend** that much money on this burger" in that case.

Comment: But even if you're certain, you can still use the language that relates to it being hypothetical.

Comment: I see your points. As far as I understand you are speaking about future hypotheticals. I guess, I should tell the background of the statement in my question.
There was a guy who was overcharged at a burger shop. When the guy realised that, he called his bank manager to solve the problem. The bank manager agreed that there had been a mistake and blocked the transaction and said the phrase "It does seems strange..." What hypothetical future is he talking about?

Comment: Ah, that's because he's speaking in general. He found the claim that the charge was too high credible because it would be very strange for *anyone* to spend that much in a burger bar.

Comment: Oh, I see:) I really appreciate your help. Would you be so kind to answer the last question? Is it possible to use “could” instead of “would” speaking about general ability there? Or maybe if the bank manager using the word ‘someone’ means the guy calling him; what’s more, he’s talking about unreal past, so “It does seem strange that someone could have spent so much...”? Is that possible? Thank you in advance:)

Comment: "Could" would suggest that's it's surprising that someone had the ability or opportunity to spend that much; "would" would suggest that it's surprising that someone would choose to do so.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you very much:) And what about "would/could have spent"? Is it grammatically correct in that context?

Comment: That just moves it from being a general statement to one that refers specifically to the past. The grammar is different, but in this context there's little practical difference.

Comment: You're my hero!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be more clear this way:

> It does seem strange that someone **would potentially spend** that much money in a burger shop.

Comment: I see your points:) As far as I understand you are speaking about future hypotheticals. I guess, I should tell the background of the statement in my question. There was a guy who was overcharged at a burger shop. When the guy realised that, he called his bank manager to solve the problem. The bank manager agreed that there had been a mistake, he blocked the transaction and said the phrase "It does seems strange..." What hypothetical future is he talking about?